# If two glyphs representing one phoneme is a "digraph," what is one glyph representing two phonemes called?

Tags: terminology, phonemes

Two glyphs representing one phoneme is a "digraph," but what is it called when one glyph represent two phonemes? For example, the Greek letter ξ (represents the two grouped phonemes, /ks/) or ψ (represents the two grouped phonemes, /ps/).

Comment: This source just calls them "biconsonantal symbols": https://books.google.com/books?id=8pXhAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=greek+psi+zeta+xi+letters+double&source=bl&ots=okIwFo_Djd&sig=qET0_BnGOB57BtOSkHq0nAsJfzU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz66LN7dfJAhUM5mMKHXA8AhYQ6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=biconsonantal%20symbols&f=false